# how to programmatically detect a new file in a sharepoint shared folder

Tags: sharepoint

I am using wss3.0 and I need a way to listen on a shared folder library for file changes that are coming from users and check out those files and copy them somewhere else on disk. It's almost like an alert functionality, but every time it happens instead of emailing people, it needs to run some code to check out the new files and copy them to a network location.

the best solution that I can come up with is creating some custom timer job and check which files have changed since my last successful run but then I will need to save my last successful run date time somewhere.

If anybody has a better idea, they are more than welcome to share it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add Event Receiver to this library, and every time an item is added it would start. Then inside Event Receiver you would copy the file to your disk location.